In python, when raising an exception from an except block, is there a way to stop a traceback?
This code:
def abc():
    raise ValueError()

def xyz():
    try:
        raise TypeError()
    except TypeError:
        abc()

xyz()

creates the following traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in xyz
TypeError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in xyz
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in abc
ValueError

The issue is that xyz() realizes that whatever it tries first may not succeed (in this case, it just raises TypeError), and it calls abc() as a backup plan.  The fact we raised an exception in the body of xyz() is of no consequence, and if it shows up in a chain of exceptions, it's just misleading noise.
That we got an exception in abc(), however, is a real error, and I want to see it.  I would like to find a way to print abc's exception without seeing xyz's exception.  The problem is that only xyz knows this is the case.
abc() could easily suppress the incoming chain of exceptions with raise ValueError() from None, but abc() doesn't know about xyz, so it doesn't know that it's caller is handling an inconsequential exception, so it doesn't know whether 'from None' is a good idea (for all it knows, it's caller could have hit a real error).
Similarly, the caller of xyz() could decide just to print the last exception without the rest of a chain, but the caller of xyz() doesn't necessarily know what xyz() is doing internally.
I think the only good place to handle this in inside xyz() itself, but I don't see a way of doing that short of not calling abc() from an except block.  That's certainly possible, but the code gets crufty, particularly in larger examples.
Is there a way that xyz can call abc from its except block but not have its own exception "in the chain"?

"Don't nest exception throwing" really. E.g. try_abc = False, then instead of running abc() inside your exception block, set try_abc = True, then after the try/except check that flag and run abc if it's true.

"I don't see a way of doing that short of not calling abc() from an except block" - taking abc() out of the except block is by far the best option. Anything else runs into all sorts of messy problems and edge cases. For example, trying to remove context info after the fact requires a lot of highly fiddly code to handle longer __context__ chains, __cause__, and ExceptionGroups, and can't affect any processing abc does with the exception before returning - for example, if abc calls logging.exception().

Since the traceback is not really information you should have a user deal with, and knowing what the context is in which an exception was raised should be valuable to you as a developer, I don't really see why what you are trying to do is needed.
However, it can be done, for example:
abc_fails = False
xyz_fails = False


def abc():
    if abc_fails:
        raise ValueError()
    print('abc success')


def xyz():
    try:
        if xyz_fails:
            raise TypeError()
        print('xyz success')
        return
    except TypeError:
        pass
    abc()


xyz()

abc_fails  and xyz_fails and the print statements were added to allow you to model and test what will actually happen - try the various combinations to see the different outcomes.
Here, if a TypeError occurs in xyz, it gets handled (just a pass here) and the function then continues with a call to abc. If no TypeError occurs, the function terminates before that.
However, again, there should be no reason to do this unless your function xyz actually successfully handles the TypeError. Otherwise, it makes more sense to have it show up in the trace. And whatever script makes it to an end user should not use the trace to communicate what went wrong, but have descriptive error messages that may suggest how to remedy the issue.
